# Unable to connect to Jupyter Notebook on Google Cloud

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-dl-platform

I am unable to access jupyter notebook after starting my virtual machine on Google cloud. I type the code below on the shell prompt:

```
jupyter notebook
```

This returns some information about the notebook server including:

> [I 02:28:31.858 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
>   [I 02:28:31.858 NotebookApp] http://(my-fastai-instance2 or 127.0.0.1):8081/

However, when I try to access jupyter notebook at this address, the browser just returns a message saying it is unable to establish connection at that server address.

Comment: You might find it easier to use GCP's AI Platform Notebooks instead.  It's a pre-configured jupyter notebook with various popular ML libraries installed, and you don't need to SSH to connect to it

Answer (score 3):

Resolved using:

```
gcloud compute ssh <zone> <instance name> <port number>.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need try in web browser this address:
http://localhost:{your port}/tree

Answer (score 0):

insatall localtunnel :
localtunnel exposes your localhost to the world for easy testing and sharing! No need to mess with DNS

```
npm install -g localtunnel
```

after that run this command on port you are using

```
lt --port 8000
```

if the url wasn't working :
go set the configuration mentioned in the message from jupyter :

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
```

in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`, e.g. `/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` in your user image if using container-based deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

- `gcloud compute ssh --zone=YOURZONE jupyter@INSTANCENAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080`

After login to cloud with that, open browser and type `localhost:8080` and you should have **jupyter**.

Answer (score 0):

This also should work by tunneling `jupyter` via `ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine -nNT -L 8888:localhost:8888 vm_external_IP` and then `localhost:8888` in your browser